# ModalNavigationDrawer causes IconButton click event to be invalid

Tags: java

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MineView(authViewModel: AuthViewModel = viewModel()) {

    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(initialValue = DrawerValue.Closed)

    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val navController = LocalNavigation.current

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer
                ),
                title = { Text(text = "我的") },
                actions = {
                    IconButton(onClick = { scope.launch { drawerState.open() } }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.Menu,
                            contentDescription = "菜单"
                        )
                    }
                },
            )
        },
    ) { innerPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(innerPadding)
        ) {
            Text(text = "Mine")
        }
    }

    showBottomBar.value = !drawerState.isOpen

    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl) {
        ModalNavigationDrawer(
            drawerState = drawerState,
            drawerContent = {
                ModalDrawerSheet(modifier = Modifier.width(200.dp)) {
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                    ) {
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                        // 将退出登录按钮放置在底部中间
                        Button(
                            onClick = {
                                authViewModel.logout()
                                scope.launch {
                                    drawerState.close()
                                }
                                navController.navigate(RouterEnums.HOME.router)
                            },
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 20.dp)
                        ) {
                            Text(text = "退出登录")
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        ) {}
    }
}
```

IconButton onClick in TopAppBar does not take effect.

It will take effect after moving the ModalNavigationDrawer to the Scaffold content, but the Drawer will be under the topBar.

I can't make the ModalNavigationDrawer above the topBar and at the same time make the iconButton click event in the topBar take effect.

please help me thanks.